# How to make a full screen section for a parallax site?

Tags: jquery, css, web, fullscreen

How do I make the first section of a parallax site full screen?

I have searched the web for this issue for ages, yet I'm coming up blank despite the fact that almost every parallax site I saw does this. The best I got was scrolldeck.js, but this is not exactly what I want as this makes every section of the site full screen.

Examples:

http://zindustry.com/index.php and http://cecchi.net/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You will need to calculate the user's height and width using:

`$(window).width()` and `$(window).height()`

Then use the `$(window).resize(function() {}` to accommodate any changes and recalculate the height/width to fit their view.